# Splitting strings and printing the capitalized first characers in C

Tags: c, cs50, toupper, putchar

I am working on a code that takes the string containing the name of someone and prints the initials of that name capitalized, whenever I run my code, I keep getting the initials printed twice, which I don't know how to fix this issue and get the desired output.

Here is my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    string name = GetString();
    char* pointer;
    pointer = strtok(name, " ");
    while (pointer != NULL)
    {
        printf("%c", putchar(toupper(pointer[0])));
        pointer = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

when I run the code with for example: ahmed salah eldin

output:

```
AASSEE
```

I just need :

```
ASE
```

Comment: Why are you using putchar *and* printf?  They both output a character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `printf()` and `putchar()` you just need one of them. When you call `putchar()` it returns the output character which is then passed to `printf()` and is output again.

Change that to

```
fputc(toupper(pointer[0]), stdout);
```